# Android Studio: android sources kinda broken

Tags: android, android-studio

On android studio, when i try to understand what a class really does, i like to see the source code.
The problem is that even if i have installed "Sources for *the sdk im using*" from the sdk manager i get thousands errors in classes, like missing methods or missing classes.

Here is an example while i was trying to understand the startActivity impl:[image]

My application compiles and runs perfectly, so its not a huge problem if i dont have android sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform sources are there for a reference, not to be compiled. The SDK for app development does not have all the platform building blocks that are there when compiling the Android platform itself.

It's annoying yes but there's not really anything you can or need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an Android Studio association error.
You can copy the red sections, open the corresponding classes, and search for them